# Parsing CAN frames from a ByteArray

Tags: serialization, kotlin, rx-java

Here's my method used for parsing a `ByteArray` into multiple [frames of CAN interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Frames). It works now correctly but it's somewhat ugly in my opinion.

It's written in Kotlin with use of RxJava2

```
private fun parseCanFrameBytes(frame: ByteArray): Observable<CanFrame> {
    return Observable.create { emitter ->
        var index = 0
        while (index < frame.size) {
            val byte = frame[index]

            if(byte xor IFM_FRAME_HEADER == BYTE_ZERO) {
                try {
                    val ifmIndex = index
                    val length = frame[ifmIndex + 1].toInt()
                    val dlc1 = length - 3
                    val dlc2 = length - 5
                    val command = frame[ifmIndex + 2].toInt()
                    val data = frame.copyOfRange(ifmIndex + 3, ifmIndex + 2 + length)
                    val isChecksumValid = frame[ifmIndex + 2 + length].toInt() == frame.copyOfRange(ifmIndex, ifmIndex + 2 + length).calculate8XorChecksum()
                    if (!isChecksumValid) {
                        index++
                        continue
                    }

                    val canFrame = when (command) {
                        0 -> {
                            val pgn = data.copyOfRange(0, 2).toHexString()
                            CanFrame(
                                    type = "DLC1",
                                    pgn = pgn,
                                    id = pgn,
                                    value = data.copyOfRange(2, 2 + dlc1).toHexString(),
                                    ts = timestamp(),
                                    data = frame.copyOfRange(ifmIndex, ifmIndex + 4 + length).toHexString()
                            )
                        }
                        2 -> {
                            val pgn = data.copyOfRange(0, 4).toHexString()
                            CanFrame(
                                    type = "DLC2",
                                    pgn = pgn,
                                    id = pgn,
                                    value = data.copyOfRange(4, 4 + dlc2).toHexString(),
                                    ts = timestamp(),
                                    data = frame.copyOfRange(ifmIndex, ifmIndex + 4 + length).toHexString()
                            )
                        }
                        else -> null
                    } ?: continue

                    emitter.onNext(canFrame)
                    index = ifmIndex + length + 4
                } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    index++
                }
            } else {
                index++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more context, what exactly is `CanFrame` ?

Comment: I don't think that's important at all. What I want to achieve is more concise and better looking code. It's pretty niche thing but if you want you can read about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus

Comment: I'd recommend you to read [Simon's guide to a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)

Answer (score 1):

#### Nesting Branches

You were worried your code might be a bit ugly. I consider deeply nested branches *ugly* aka a penalty in readability when they can easily be avoided. For example, your function indents the entire while-loop body to perform this little branch at the end:

> ```
> if (byte xor IFM_FRAME_HEADER == BYTE_ZERO) {
>     // branch body ..
> } else {
>     index++
> }
> ```

You could invert the branch condition, use an early `continue` and avoid nesting branches.

```
if (byte xor IFM_FRAME_HEADER != BYTE_ZERO) {
    index++
    continue
}
// other code in while-loop no longer needs indentation ..
```

#### Shifting the input

You have 3 occasions where you shift the input array to the next index `index++`. 2 of these have conditions that guard when to shift, the 3th is an exception handler for type `IllegalArgumentException`. Consider refactoring the code to have only a single connection point in the code where you perform the shift `index++`. This increases maintainability of the code. You can do this be either (1) trying to avoid the exception and using a condition instead, and use a single flag `shouldShift` marked `true` on any of the conditions or (2) throw exceptions for all conditions that require shifting and have a single exception handler performing the shift.

#### Flow Integrity

The callback invocation  `emitter.onNext(canFrame)` sits within the `try-catch` block. This means that if the callback would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` you'd be shifting the input `index++` while you shouldn't have. Ensure callback invocation does not trigger such shifting.

Answer (score 0):

Probably very little beautification. I would be curious to see someone beautify it and prove me wrong. Initially I thought you could use Kotlin streams on the frame ByteArray. This way you could have done something equivalent to `frame.filterIndexed(..).map(it->CanFrame(..))` etc. However then I noticed you were doing random access on the ByteArray: ex: `ifmIndex + length + 4` , `frame.copyOfRange(ifmIndex + 3, ifmIndex + 2 + length)` which would negate the purpose of streams which go one by one.

Comment: Also try using Arrow FP library (arrow-kt.io)